# Find if a specified class is present in the HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, class, popup, alert

I want to have a alert box when there is a certain class. For example if there is a class called: "test" than there should popup an alert that says: Test.

How can i achive this?

Comment: add what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "li" ).each(function( index ) { //check the class name of element li
    if($( this ).attr("class")=='rest'){ // check the equality
     alert("present class name  "+$( this ).attr("class")); // show alertbox
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
  <li class='test'>foo</li><!--element with class name-->
  <li class='rest'>bar</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are just searching a single tag. What if I have the same class in `div` not in `li` ? Also, you don't need a 80KB third-party file to do it. Even the user didn't mention `jquery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this when the document is loaded using the `window.onload` method. `document.querySelector` is used to find an element with a selector . If it cannot find and element, it just returns `null`.

[MDN Docs for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
window.onload = function(){
    if(document.querySelector(".test")){alert("test class name present")};
    if(document.querySelector(".test2")){alert("test2 class name present")};
    if(document.querySelector(".test3")){alert("test3 class name present")};
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
test
</div>

<div class="test2">
test2
</div>

<div class="test2 test3">
test2 test3
</div>

<div class="nothing">
nothing
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "div" ).each(function( index,element) { // if u want find the specific element use ID
  var arry=$(this).attr("class").split(" ");
  $.each(arry,function( index1,element1) {
    alert("element found "+element1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test test1 test2"></div>

<div class="test4"></div>
```